# Java card for running cryptographic protocol

Tags: performance, smartcard, javacard

My question is about performance of JavaCard smart-card on `AT90SC25672RCT` chip.
The matter is that I want to develop project related to cryptography using JavaCard for educational purposes.

Right now is time to buy smart-card and that's why I wonder if card with this chip will cover my needs. The matter is that I've decided to use some [cryptographic protocol](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~plafourc/teaching/pace.pdf) that will require some calculations both on desktop and smart-card side.

So my question is addressed to people that have JavaCard now and can tell me if it is possible to run random generator and compute couple of hash values in within sane amount of time or I should use some protocol that requires less calculations?

Recommendations devices or minimal requirements are also welcome.

Comment: For pace you hardly need just a random number generator and a "couple of hash values". PACE is an asymmetric protocol. You need a *fast* asymmetric co-processor.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes can you please give some example of publicly traded smart-cart to have some kind of landmark?

Comment: did you research into what the crypto-coprecessor is capable of?

Comment: @PaulBastian I did lots of things. But I cannot go into all of them :)

Comment: This was obiously not meant to you Maarten! I'm aware you are doing a lot on this site.

Comment: @threadcreator: I don't know this chip but I can tell you that PACE requires for example EC PÜoint addition which is not covered by standard java card so you need to make sure your crypto processor supports it additionally

Comment: @PaulBastian Ah, sorry, mistaken identity - but this is also related to im_infamous. I can just tell you that Java Card currently requires an extended/proprietary API to perform PACE. PACE contains (the equivalent of) two key agreements + RNG & MAC. OK, OK, for point addition or modular multiplication for DH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, smart cards in general have co-processors. Symmetric ones for DES and AES family of algorithms and asymmetric ones for RSA and elliptic curves.

I don't know what you consider a sane amount of time, but generating signatures is never a problem (well below one second), while generating a 4096 bit RSA key pair on the card may last minutes.

The typical bottleneck is the I/O interface, heavily depending on the card and the reader at hand (among others by the external clock). This is the reason, why nobody will sent a document of megabytes to a card, just to get the hash computed, but will hash externally. The small random numbers to be hashed within cryptographic protocols are of course no problem. Cards are getting faster on the I/O side too, but the proven approach will remain with us for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know which smart card has that specific chip inside, but nowadays smart cards are really powerful. They not only has the ability to generate random numbers and hash values but also they can do some cryptography functions and signature generation and verification such as RSA, 3DES, AES and so on.

Fortunately you can see a list of supported algorithms for a big list of smart cards [here.](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xsvenda/jcsupport.html)

Comment: As far as I understood this list(pretty exhaustive, though) designed for **supported** algorithms while I was seeking for estimation of **execution time** for most common cryptographic primitives computed on smart-card.

Comment: Except for keypair generation (almost) all operations are completed in considerable time if they are supported